# How should I group unit tests using C# and NUnit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I've a class with a lot of unit tests in C# (using NUnit 2.5.8) and I'd like to group the unit tests together based on which area of the class's functionality I'm testing (so I can quickly choose which set to run in the NUnit UI).

I know I could refactor the class into smaller components, which would solve the problem, but are there any other ways to do this without completely re-designing the production code?

Comment: Why does the layout of your unit tests depend on how the production code is designed???

Comment: @Pieter: By convention, I've always had one TestFixture per production class. Clearly there are better ways of doing things as explained in Jason's answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not a `[TestFixture]` (separate class) for each area of functionality that you want to test?

```
class ClassThatDoesTooMuch {
    // functionality related to opening a database connection
    // functionality related to file management
    // functionality related to solving world hunger
}

[TestFixture]
public class ClassThatDoesTooMuchDatabaseConnectionTests { // }

[TestFixture]
public class ClassThatDoesTooMuchFileManagementTests { // }

[TestFixture]
public class ClassThatDoesTooMuchWorldHungerSolutionTests { // }
```

Comment: So obvious I'm embarrassed not to have though of it myself. *shakes*

Comment: Additionally you could use a `[Category("ClassThatDoesTooMuch")]` on each of the test fixtures so you can still run all of the test related to `ClassThatDoesTooMuch` at the same time.